Sky texture changes settings when I render
In Blender 4.2, using a sky texture, the settings for sun rotation and height keep resetting on their own when I try to render. This began when setting this lighting as default startup file. I reset factory settings on startup file and it keeps resetting on its own. Any ideas?

Maybe those settings has an animation key ; if that's the case, they should appear yellow or green. Right Click / Clear Keyframe.

Thank you, but there no animation key. I think the problem was that using the sun position add-on it wants to control the sky texture rotation and elevation.
